# How to grant permissions in Local Security Policy like "Log on as a service" via script specifically in windows 10?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-10, local-security-policy

I've seen lots of posts about this for earlier versions of windows pointing towards RSAT and ntrights.exe but neither of those solutions work for Windows 10.  I'm looking for a solution preferably in powershell or batch.

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't a easy task. Im using a 100 line PowerShell script which uses **scedit.exe** to do that reliable.

Comment: I posted this to outline the problem specifically with windows 10.  It took me several days of searching to get this, so I hope this question will be a more direct resource to others.  I answered my own question below if you'd like a simpler solution.

Comment: Yes, there are third party libraries to help for that. However, If you aren't allowed to use them, this is a hard one ;-)

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm glad I wasn't crazy not being able to find a simple native solution.

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty, I figured it out.  I ended up having to use Carbon.  After running:

```
.\Carbon\Import-Carbon.ps1
```

I was able to successfully run:

```
Grant-Privilege -Identity $username -Privilege SeServiceLogonRight
```

Something to note is that the Local Security Policy manager doesn't have a refresh button.  You'll have to close and reopen the tool in order to see external changes to the policy.